# Java Streams group Map by property of its key

Tags: java, java-stream

Lets say there is next class

```
class A {
  B b
}
```

And I have initial `Map<A, List<C>>`.
How can I group A by b and get `Map<B, Map<A, List<C>>>`?

Comment: That would be something like `collect(toMap(A::getB, Function.identity()))`.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `Map<B, Map<A, List<C>>>` makes sense as the output. But, you can try something like:

```java
myAMap.keySet().stream().reduce(new HashMap<B, List<A>>(), (map, key) -> {

    if(map.get(key.b) == null) map.set(key.b, [key]);
    else if(map.get(key.b) != null) map.set(key.b, map.get(key.b).add(key));

    return map;

}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Java 9 (required for `entry()` and `flatMapping()`):

```
Map<B, Map<A, List<C>>> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey().b, Map.entry(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream())))
        .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                mapping(Entry::getValue,
                        groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                                flatMapping(Entry::getValue, toList())))));
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/fW3ibh)

It's not very pleasant reading, I know. Maybe you can do better with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would forgo Streams and take advantage of other new capabilities in the Map interface.

- check out [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) and [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V))

First, create a target map instance.

```
Map<B, Map<A, List<C>>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

- iterate thru the source map's entrySet.
- if the desired key is not present, create an entry with a `HashMap`,
  otherwise, use existing `HashMap`.
- then if the existing key is absent, put it in the inner map along with the original value.

```
for (Map.Entry<A, List<C>> e : sourceMap.entrySet()) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey().b, v->new HashMap<>())
            .putIfAbsent(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```